# Why does push_back have two overloads for lvalues and rvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Why would a class/function have two overloads, one for lvalue and one for rvalue?

Eg, from [this](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Scott-Meyers-Universal-References-in-Cpp11) video, it says we have two overloads for `vector<T>::push_back`

```
void push_back( const T& value );
void push_back( T&& value );
```

Why can't we have just one overload by value,

```
void push_back( T value );
```

If it was an lvalue, value would be copied and if it was an rvalue, value would be moved. Isn't this the way how it works and guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: move-assignment if capacity is permitting? just a guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your by-value proposition, technically there would be copy+move or move+move, whereas with the other two overloads there is a single copy or a single move.

Comment: I was recommended to use values as parameters and rely on move semantics and I am surprised to see its not followed in STL. Practically won't one of them be optimized?

Comment: @balki:  Any time some one is telling you to **always** choose one reasonable way over another, they are going to be wrong at least some of the time.  You can best serve your clients by knowing the cost of each solution and choosing the best solution for each situation.  In this case, the author of `vector<T>` has no idea how expensive the move construction of `T` may be.  `T` might even be an expensive-to-copy object without a move constructor, in which case the by-value approach costs an extra copy construction.  Additionally `vector` is used by everyone.  It has to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the point others mentioned, it would also require *changing* the old interface. And there are times when that's simply not acceptable.

Comment: Why would it hurt to change a `const Type&` interface to `Type`? Shouldn't be completely source compatible?

Comment: @balki: Source compatible, maybe. ABI compatible? *No.*